# Seed, Increment and Current Value of an Identity Column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to get initial seed value of an identity column (Primary Key Column) in Mysql.

There is a function for this functionality in SQL `IDENT_SEED(TABLE_NAME)`

I also need to get the incrementing and current value of the identity column, like SQL's `IDENT_INCR("table name")` and `IDENT_CURRENT("table name")`.

I have already searched on `"INFORMAION_SCHEMA"` tables like columns,tables and statistics but couldn't get my result.

How would you write the following query on MySQL?

```
SELECT IDENT_SEED(TABLE_NAME) AS Seed, IDENT_INCR(TABLE_NAME) AS Increment, 
       IDENT_CURRENT(TABLE_NAME) AS Current_Identity
FROM
       INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE   
       OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(TABLE_NAME), 'TableHasIdentity') = 1
       AND TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
```

Comment: Would that help you? https://www.bram.us/2008/07/30/mysql-get-next-auto_increment-value-fromfor-table/

Comment: please remove irrelevant tags

Comment: @Evaldas Buinauskas This link only gives auto increment value alone but my requirement is different

Comment: What are those terms??  Anything like `auto_increment_offset` and `auto_increment_increment`?  Maybe like `LAST_INSERT_ID()`?

Comment: Once you have the values, what will you do with them?  (Maybe we can get to the ultimate goal by some other means.)

Comment: Not last inserted value. We need to find out the initial value identity_seed and offcourse the increment value of that identity column and am not much sure about auto_increment_offset and auto_increment_increment , so how can find these things from information_schema.